# Is CCScene replace during CCTransition possible?

Tags: iphone, background, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d, ccscene

Calling `replaceScene:` with a `CCScene` on `CCDirector` which is during a `CCTransition` results in `dealloc` not being called on any scene used, moreover, after this operation any scene is not being displayed.

Here is [a link to the sample project](https://bitbucket.org/wladeczek/transitionbackgroundproblem)

Shortest way to obtain this behavior is such method (I mean reproducing the problem):

```
 SceneOne *destScene = [SceneOne node];
CCTransitionFade *transition = [[CCTransitionFade alloc]initWithDuration:2 scene:destScene];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:transition];
double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:[SceneTwo node]];
});
```

My question is: is there any feasible way to replace scenes when the `CCTransition` is being performed by the `CCDirector`?

I have implemented a delegate callback from `CCDirector` informing me about ending scene replacement, but this is never called if I push the iPhone home button during `CCTransition`.

If the answer is no, is there a cocos2d-iphone way to achieve goal described below?

Originally, this problem arised when I wanted to add "loading scene" when `applicationDidEnterBackground` (as a background task) or `applicationWillEnterForeground`, but I realized it has nothing to do with background execution. My ultimate goal is to provide seamless user experience while a game is waiting for Game Center authentication handler being called, and a "loading scene" being displayed from the very start of the app awaked from background would be sufficient (not only preventing user interaction which can be done many ways, but not showing previous game UI to the user). However, this solution is susceptible to the problem described above - if user taps the home button during scene transition he is going to get a very strange screen after bringing the game from background.

EDIT: After some more research I didn't find any satisfactory solution to replacing scene during `CCTransition`, however, problem described above was solved by not calling `replaceScene` but by adding a "loading" `CCLayer` to the visible `CCScene`, as @LearnCocos2D (thanks Steffen) suggested. This is not perfect, since adding a child during scene transition still has some narrow window (in the sense of running time) when strange results occur, but it is much better than replacing the scene. I would like to mention that it only concerns me when testing my game on 3GS, since newer devices are significantly faster and it is very difficult to reproduce the problem of "home button" clicking during `CCTransition` on something faster than 3GS.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted the shortest possible code giving the whole idea out - a scene transition is interrupted by another instant replace.

Comment: display the loading bit as a layer on top of the current scene, if need be don't use any transitions whatsoever. You certainly shouldn't call replaceScene again during a transition, so you could also block loading screens until the current transition is over. Don't mind what the user sees, it's more important that it won't crash.